# why ngClass is not a standard property binding

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm new to Angular, just a question on the difference of Built-in Directives and property binding, below is some code I saw:

```html
// ... just js expression, not relevant here
<div [ngClass]="'text-white' + ...">
 Hello, World.
</div>
<div class="form-group m-2">
 <label>Name:</label>
 <input class="form-control" [value]=... />
</div>
```

so why we can't make ngClass a standard property binding just like [value] as:

```
<div [class]="'text-white' + ...">
```

why it has to be a directive?

Comment: The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass) might be helpful.

Comment: @KirkLarkin  it is not for me, it didn't tell why ngClass cannot be a standard property binding

Answer (score 1):

Literal values should be passed without brackets around the attribute.

```
ngclass="text-white"
```

If the value is variable you can pass it dynamically by wrapping the attribute in brackets:

Component.ts

```
 myclass: string = 'text-white';
```

Component.html

```
[ngclass]="myclass"
```

You can also pass an object where each project is a CSS class name and the value `true` or `false`, `true` stating the class will be used `false` stating it will not.

```
[ngClass]="{'row': true, 'container': false}"
```

There is nothing stopping you building that dynamically too.

Component.ts

```
getClassses(): any {
 return {'row': true, 'container': false}
}
```

Component.html

```
[ngClass]="getClasses()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to use `[class]` directly. It's even possible to combine with `ngClass` like in the following:

In app.component.ts

```
isActive = true;
componentClass = 'my-class';
```

In app.component.html

```
<div [class]="componentClass" [ngClass]="{ active: isActive }">hello</div>
```

If you inspect your html you will see this result:

```html
<div _ngcontent-gej-c0="" class="my-class active">div</div>
```

But I wouldn't recommend it. When you will be constructing reusable components better let class attribute available for the end developer.